# Get Video Duration from Video Metadata (MXF) in Python

Tags: python, file, video, metadata, codec

I have a directory of about 300 MXF files, each of which may not have the same duration.  My goal is to obtain the video duration of each file, and store it in a plain-text table (with the filepath as the key and the duration as the value).  This would be easy to do in Python, if I knew how to obtain this information from the MXF file.

I don't understand enough about the internal file structure of these types of video files to know where to look to extract this information by myself, but surely there's a package written that can do this.

**Does anybody know how this can be done in Python?**  If so, can you give an example on how to obtain this metadata from an MXF file?

If this is relevant, all of them were encoded using the ACV-Intra Class 100 codec, 1080p 59.94 fps.

Comment: I would use ffmpeg/ffprobe

Answer (score 1):

You can use ffmpeg to get the metadata info as suggested in the comments.

Pythng wrappers exist for ffmpeg - https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python appears to be well supported any this time.

This library includes examples to extract metadata:

```js
probe = ffmpeg.probe(args.in_filename)
video_stream = next((stream for stream in probe['streams'] if stream['codec_type'] == 'video'), None)
width = int(video_stream['width'])
height = int(video_stream['height'])
```

Comment: This should be the answer! I can finally run it indipendently of system ffmpeg installation